# Why do my files fail checksums when transferring to esata dive but not when transfered off the external?

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, esata

I have been using Teracopy to verify and the large movie files show artifacting after transfer and fail checksum, small files do not fail, only large files seem to. When I transfer files off the external hard drive no such failure of checksums occur on any of the files. Could this be a bad cable, or maybe a bad external interface or e-sata interface on my computer?

I have tried two interfaces for e-sata, one with a PCI card the other on the motherboard, both with similar results, so what maybe the reason if a bad hard drive or external case maybe the problem?

Comment: Does this happen at specific boundaries like files > 2 GB? Or what sizes do you have there?

Comment: Well, it occurs on files at the 700MB and larger such as dvd or larger, it has also messed up photos which are only a few mb, but smaller txt files seem fine. Pretty much all files except very small ones. Maybe I'll try a new case and cable and see if that works if not then off to get a new drive, too bad since this one's a 2tb and I'm not buying anymore of them, this would be my second bad one in a row, back to 1tb for me and no green drives for me.